# How to use auto layout with scrollView in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

I try to add a view to my scrollView, when i set the width manually to the greenView it works fine, but if i try to use constrants it seems like the constraints are not working. Do i something wrong? Can anyone help?

Here is my controller and view code:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView(){
        self.view = UserProfileView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}


import UIKit
import Material

class UserProfileView: UIView {

    fileprivate var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    convenience init(){
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.24, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)
        prepareScrollView()
        prepareMainView()
    }

    fileprivate func prepareScrollView() {
        self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollView.width, height: 1678)
        self.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    fileprivate func prepareMainView() {
        let greenView = UIView()
        greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        greenView.height = 100


        self.scrollView.addSubview(greenView)

        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let views = [
            "scrollView": self.scrollView!,
            "greenView": greenView,
        ] as [String : Any]



        let scrollViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView]|", metrics: nil, views: views)
        let scrollViewWidth = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|", metrics: nil, views: views)
        let greenViewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView][greenView][scrollView]|", metrics: nil, views: views)
        let greenViewVerticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView][greenView]|", metrics: nil, views: views)

        self.addConstraints(scrollViewHeight)
        self.addConstraints(scrollViewWidth)
        self.addConstraints(greenViewHorizontalConstraint)
        self.addConstraints(greenViewVerticalConstraint)

    }

}
```

Comment: That's "old style" coding of the constraints, so I may be wrong here. Are you getting conflicting constraint warnings? I'm reading two sets V/H, one with both views and one with just the scrollView.

Comment: No i don't get any conflicts. Do you have another way to do this?

Comment: LayoutAnchors. It's basically different syntax. Explaining is much too long for a comment (and it's not an answer) so here's a link to a blog post: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/. It's in Swift 2 syntax but nothing has changed with Swift 3. You can decide if it's easier than usingVisual Forma Language.

Comment: I know this way, but it is the same just more verbose.

Comment: I created LayoutAnchors but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see nowhere in your code where you activate the constraints.

Notice below how we activate the constraints.

```
//create
let childredView = UIView()
childredView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
childredView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

//add it
self.view.addSubview(childredView)
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: childredView)

//set constraints
let views = ["childrenView": childredView]
let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[childrenView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
let horizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[childrenView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
let all = vertical + horizontal

//activate them
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(all)
```

If your using Layout Anchors, make sure you add `isActive = true` At the end of each one YAnchor you create. For example:

```
item.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I add the constraints to the view, so they are active. It works pretty fine with UIView but not with a UIScrollView.

Comment: I also tried the way with the activate, but still the same problem.